# How to send raw multitouch trackpad data under Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, multi-touch, trackpad

The end goal is to take touch input from an iOS device, send it over a websocket, accept it on the Mac OS X side, and send it through the system so everything using the private multitouch framework to accept input sees the data as if it were normal multitouch trackpad data.

The synthesize sub-project under https://github.com/calftrail/Touch seems like a good place to start. However it seems like the developer created it with the intent of taking valid multitouch input (from a magic mouse when there was arbitrarily little software support from Mac OS X), and piping it as multitouch trackpad input. I need to create valid/acceptable multitouch trackpad out of thin air (with just sequences of touch locations, not real HID data).

In deep here. Help, someone. :)

Comment: I believe (from what little I know) that a key part is "Assistive Devices". I'd love to know the full answer to this myself (mouse/trackpad + keyboard api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad you found my TouchSynthesis subproject — I think it *will* let you do what you need, since internally it is split up as you want it. [Please note however that this code is GPL licensed, i.e. virally open source, unlike many Mac libraries.]

You can treat [TouchSynthesis.m](https://github.com/calftrail/Touch/blob/master/TouchSynthesis/TouchSynthesis.m) as example code for using the [TouchEvents "library"](https://github.com/calftrail/Touch/blob/master/TouchSynthesis/TouchEvents.h) which provides support for your specific question via one "simple" function: `tl_CGEventCreateFromGesture`

The basic gist is that `tl_CGEventCreateFromGesture` takes in a dictionary of gesture+touch data and will return a CGEvent that you can inject via Quartz Event Services into the system. A gesture event is required to send what becomes NSTouch data, but IIRC could be a fairly generic "gesture" type rather than zoom/pan/etc.

This is sort of a halfway-private solution: Apple [support injecting CGEvents into the system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) [at least outside The Sandbox? …I've since lost interest in their platforms so haven't researched that one…] so that part is "fine", but the actual CGEvent I create is of an undocumented type, the format for which I had to figure out via hex dumps and some Darwin source code HID headers they shared. It's that work that "TouchEvents.m" implements — that's how [Sesamouse](http://calftrail.com/sesamouse) could "create valid/acceptable multitouch trackpad out of thin air" — and it should already be separate from the private framework MultitouchSupport stuff that read in the Magic Mouse input.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. It's good to know it can be done. It's not intended for any kind of closed source release, so I'm not worried about sandbox or GPL. I am a little hesitant though, having little understanding of what to send to tl_CGEventCreateFromGesture, and not knowing if this still works on 10.7 -> 10.9.
Nevertheless, thank you for the (rapid) help!

Comment: can you suggest how to do binding between MTTouch object and TUIO  messages?I can figure out you get a series of MTTouch objects and then call tl_CGEventCreateFromGesture to make it a CGEventRef and then inject into system.I'm not sure how to get MTTouch object.

Comment: The MTTouch objects come from Apple's private multitouch framework. An unofficial header is [here](https://github.com/calftrail/Touch/blob/master/TouchSynthesis/MultitouchSupport.h) and example usage can be seen [here](https://github.com/calftrail/Touch/blob/master/TouchSynthesis/TouchSynthesis.m#L558). This framework may have changed a bit in Mavvrix…I'm not sure because I haven't diagnosed, but that is when my Sesamouse app stopped working.